# How to consume soap web services in javascript?

Tags: javascript, cordova

Can any one tell me how to consume soap web services in javascript.I want use this web services in phonegap (or) How to consume web services in phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

Make an AJAX call to the service URL and manage the response on the callback.

Using jQuery for simplicity:

```
$.ajax({
    url: yourSoapServiceUrl,
    success: function (soapResponse) {
        //Do whatever you need with soapResponse
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Added example code.